# Cron expression with exception on a range time in a specific day

Tags: cron

I try to create a cron expression like this:  every 15 minutes except on sunday from 16h to 18h.

I have tried a few generators, but can't find the way to write the "except on sunday between 16h and 18h.

Could someone help me or give me a ressource maybe ?